# Why are ipython and python returning different outputs when i call a cython extension?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython, cython

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and coding algorithms that use Cython extensions in order to project and back-project large matrices.

I've been coding this for 2 months now and I just realised that when I call my test scripts with Python from the CLI or iPython, i get different outputs and results.

So in answer to some of the questions the software is composed of three layers: the C code (used to perform the forward and back projections), the Cython and the algorithms.

comptest.py (the algorithm) looks *something* like this:

```
import time
from cythonmodule import forproj
from cythonmodule import backproj

def Algorithm(data,imax):
    toc=time.clock()
    res=[]
    print('Algorithm in progress')
    for i in range(imax):
        a = forproj(data)
        b = backproj(data)
        res.append(a,b)
        tic = time.clock()
        if i ==1:
             tval=(tic-toc)*imax
             print('Estimated time until completion (s):'+str(tval))
    print('Algorithm complete')
    return sum(res)


initval=np.arange(45).reshape(3,3,5)
algres = Algorithm(initval,100)
```

Now when i build the Cython using `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` I get different results between ipython and python as mentioned above.

```
$ python comptest.py
Algorithm in progress.
Estimated time until completion (s): 39.288388
Algorithm complete.
```

The output is very different for iPython, both in time taken and final output:

```
$ipython comptest.py
Algorithm in progress.
Esitmated time until completetion (s): 14.63456
Algorithm complete.
```

Since python itself cannot be changing the values this drastically, I can only assume that the Cython extensions (and therefore the underlying C-functions) being run by Python and iPython must be different.

I have made sure the python versions are the same (2.7.13). Is there a way for me to see what extensions Python and iPython are calling? Where is the actual Cython code located in my directories? Can i retrieve what iPython is using?

UPDATE:

So I've been looking at the LineProfile outputs for the python and ipython and ive just realised that the outputs are very different for these two, for not only the backproj and proj but also functions implemented by python.

When I print the sys.version for both, however, it returns the same result:

Python:

```
>>> sys.version
'2.7.13 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Dec 20 2016, 23:09:15) \n[GCC          4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)]'
```

Line Profile:

```
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
62                                           def Algorithm(data,imax):
63         1            4      4.0      0.0      res1=[]
64         1            2      2.0      0.0      res2=[]
65       101          113      1.1      0.0      for i in range(imax):
66       100      5143186  51431.9     73.6          a=forptoj(data)
67       100      1632400  16324.0     23.4          b=backproj(data)
68       100        90969    909.7      1.3          a = a.clip(min=0)
69       100        16414    164.1      0.2          b = b.clip(min=0)
70       100          221      2.2      0.0          res1.append(a)
71       100           79      0.8      0.0          res2.append(b)
72                                           
73         1       107541 107541.0      1.5      return sum(res1),sum(res2)
```

iPython:

```
In [2]: sys.version
Out[2]: '2.7.13 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Dec 20 2016, 23:09:15) \n[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)]'
```

Line profile:

```
   Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
   ==============================================================
    62                                           def Algorithm(data,imax):
    63         1            4      4.0      0.0      res1=[]
    64         1            2      2.0      0.0      res2=[]
    65       101          127      1.3      0.0      for i in range(imax):
    66       100      5926013  59260.1     75.3          a=backproj(data)
    67       100      1724570  17245.7     21.9          b=backproj(data)
    68       100        94297    943.0      1.2          a = a.clip(min=0)
    69       100        16758    167.6      0.2          b = b.clip(min=0)
    70       100          238      2.4      0.0          res1.append(a)
    71       100           72      0.7      0.0          res2.append(b)
    72                                           
    73         1       108388 108388.0      1.4      return sum(res1),sum(res2)
```

The differences are very subtle but since these two outputs should be identical, it raises the question whether python is really doing the same in both cases.

Comment: Is that repeatable? What does the next `$ python comptest.py` or `$ ipython comptest.py` print? Also it would be helpful to know what you're code is doing. Otherwise any answer will be mostly guessing.

Comment: maybe use `dis()` function to see the changes.

Comment: @MSeifert Thanks for the answer. Ill update the post now and see if you guys can make sense of it.

Comment: Can you check versions: pip show Cython

Comment: @oshaiken:
Name: Cython
Version: 0.25.2

Comment: @landolanplz and conda list Cython

Comment: I assume you are using conda?

Comment: `time.clock` is the processor time rather than the wall time on Linux, so can give odd results in multithreaded applications. I don't know why IPython should affect this (and whether it's affecting the actual speed or just how it's counted) but this seems a likely place to start looking.

Comment: @oshaiken Yes, using conda ofc: cython 0.25.2  py27_0

Comment: @DavidW Thanks for the reply. I doubt its time messing up since algres has different outputs as well but i can take a look.

Comment: @landolanplz Ah right - I hadn't realised that it produced results too. In that case I also doubt it's time. (I'd say it's most likely a bug in your Cython/C code but that is a wild guess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey so I solved the issue, somewhat. Ive checked on how conda sets up a new environment, isolated from all previous biases on the OS on this page:

https://conda.io/docs/py2or3.html

Since that resets all python versions, i checked with this and it turns out it was, in fact, the python (or maybe Cython??) messing with it. If anybody has any ideas as to why that might be the case please let me know!

Either way, setting conda up with a new environment like so:

```
$ conda create -n py27 python=2.7 anaconda
```

Then checking it out like so:

```
$source activate py27
```

This seems to have reset whatever was causing the issue with different outputs.

Its like they say, if in doubt just reset everything you possibly can!!

Thanks for the help guys, and keep on coding.